# regular expression in django for urls

Tags: python, regex, django, url

What I am trying to do is as follows

I have urls like this `/blog/1/sdc/?c=119` or `/forum/83/ksnd/?c=100` What I want to do is to redirect these to a view, so that I can change the url to `/blog/1/sdc/#c119`

One way would be to do this is to make provision in views of each of the app, where such a url maybe generated, but that is not scalable. What I want to do is to catch any url that has `?c=<some_digit>` at the end and redirect to my custom view.

Can anybody help, I am not good with regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in your urlconf, it doesn't match anything in the query string. What you'll need to do is write a middleware along the lines of this:

```
class RedirectMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        if 'c' in request.GET:
            # return a HttpResponseRedirect here
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/ for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I think middleware is a neater solution than regex in the urlconf

Comment: No problem. It's not actually possible to do this in a urlconf - it only matches the URL path, not the querystring.